# Regex: How to match a string that contains repeated pattern?

Tags: regex, string

Is there a regex pattern that will match a string that contains repeated pattern, e.g.:

```
"a"|"b","c"|"d",...,"y"|"z"
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: +1 on examples.  Do you mean "any repeated pattern" or the specific pattern you mentioned?  Give some examples and counter-examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
^"."\|"."(,"."\|".")*$
```

This will match a comma-separated list of sequences of form `"`*α*`"|"`*β*`"` where *α* and *β* can be any character.

Comment: Thanks, but it still match "a"|"b","c"|"d",aaa or "a"|"b","c"|"d",
Can u fix it? Plz

Comment: I’ve added anchors for the start and the end of the string `^…$`.

Comment: @Gumbo: I am sure that "u can fix it". ;-) Deleting my answer, +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that to truly look for a repeated pattern, you can use grouping like so:

```
<(htmltag>).*\1
```

where \1 refers to the matched string in the 1st group repeated. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense and it should be marked as the more correct answer.