# python regex pattern that matches pattern including a repeated subgroup

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am looking for a pattern that catches and substitutes:

"whatever whatever 1. [document 1] This is a document dealing with"

"whatever whatever 1. This is a document dealing with"

but of course only in the case where both numbers are the same

in general:

"whatever whatever N. [document N] This is a document dealing with"

if it helps N has to be between 1 and 1000 (i.e. max three characters)

```
import re
mystr = "whatever whatever 1. [document 1] This is a document dealing with"
mystr = re.sub(r'([1-9]+)(\s)?(\.)(\s+)(\[Document )(*****)',r'\1\2\3\4',mystr)
                 ^^^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^
```

I have to refer in ***** to the first group

I could use:

```
mystr = re.sub(r'([1-9]+)(\s)?(\.)(\s+)(\[Document )([1-9]+)',r'\1\2\3\4',mystr)
```

but of course that will inlcude cases like:
"whatever whatever 56. [document 877] This is a document dealing with"

I check a bunch of answers with no success:
[Regex: How to match a string that contains repeated pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648170/regex-how-to-match-a-string-that-contains-repeated-pattern)
[Capture repeated groups in python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603805/capture-repeated-groups-in-python-regex)
[Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex)
[Regex with repeating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097158/regex-with-repeating-groups)
[python regular expression repeating group matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659068/python-regular-expression-repeating-group-matches)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a group and a backreference to the number:

As I am not sure of your full condition to match, I am providing a minimal example here assuming the only match is a number with up to 3 digits followed by a reference of the form `[document {number}]`:

```
import re
mystr = "whatever whatever 1. [document 1] This is a document dealing with"
mystr = re.sub(r'((\d{1,3})\.)\s*\[document \2\]', r'\1', mystr)
```

output: `'whatever whatever 1. This is a document dealing with'`

**NB. In the example above the reference to consider is `\2`, you will have to update this carefully if you are using more capturing groups**

Comment: To match from a digit 1-999 `\b(([1-9][0-9]{0,2})\.)\s+\[[Dd]ocument \2]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks, but I was only providing a minimal example, the important point being IMO the backreference ;) (actually I hesitated just to put `\d+`)

Comment: Yes `([1-9]\d{0,2})` would also work of course